# How can I put a discord.py task into a cog and run it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, gmail-api, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import base64

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

class Gmail(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @tasks.loop(minutes=1)
    async def test(self):
        repeat = 0
        while repeat < 10:
            channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(795222136515723265)
            vars = Gmail.main()
            print("ran main")
            TEACHER = vars[0]
            if TEACHER != "a ":
                LINK = vars[1]
                DATE = vars[2]
                if 'Due:' in DATE:
                    DATE = DATE.split("Due: ")[1]
                else:
                    DATE = DATE
                BODY = vars[3]
                TOTAL = TEACHER + "has posted a new assignment"
                print("making embed")
                embed = discord.Embed(title=TOTAL, color = 0xff0000, url=LINK,)
                embed.add_field(name="Due Date:", value=DATE, inline=False)        
                embed.add_field(name="Details:", 
                value=BODY, inline=False)
                print("made embed")
                repeat += 1

                await channel.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                repeat += 10

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(795222136515723265)
        await channel.send("Cog has run")
        self.test.start

        
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Gmail(client))
```

this is my code of a cog. The cog itself is running (it runs the on_ready) but for some reason the task (test) has not started. Why isn't it starting? What did I do wrong? Is there anything I need to add to it to make it work? I put task.start in the on_ready command. I have removed the function main() because The post was mostly code but in the actual code it is there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add cogs for them to work. Use `client.add_cog(name)` to add the cog (if the class is in the same file). Tasks work the same way in cogs, but events don't. For events, you'll need to use the `commands.Cog.listener()` decorator instead of the `client.event` decorator. If the cog you're trying to add isn't in the same file, use extensions. Define a function named `setup` at the bottom of the file that contains the cog, with 1 parameter (it gets passed a Bot instance). Have that function add the cog, as I described above, and call `client.load_extension(filename)` somewhere in your main file. [Read the docs for cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) for more information.

Comment: to run the task I need to type [task.start()] in this case I type it in the on_ready function. If I make a cog will I have to make a on_ready function in the cog file in which I write it or can I keep it in the main file?

Comment: You'll need to start the task in the file that it's in, if you have it in the cog you need to start the task within the cog.  If you want to start it in on_ready, you'll need to create a listener for on_ready within the cog

Comment: it isn't working. I edited my qs to contain the code for the cog. The cog is running but the task isn't what am I doing wrong

Comment: You need to call `start`, it's not an attribute